# DateTime countdown and expiration

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have posts on my site that have an expiration datetime I store these in Mysql in as

```
'Y-m-d H:i:s'
```

ie. 2012-08-28 00:00:00

I convert this datetime to the format below which is passed to a jquery countdown

```
$offset.', Y, n - 1, j, H, i, s'
```

This part works the way it should.

What I am trying to do is get the current time and only get the unexpired posts from the database. The thingM that is tripping me up is that all the post have different timezones. Most of them expire at midnight but in different timezones some expire at midnight eastern while others expire midnight pacific. These are all stored as 2012-08-28 00:00:00 with a timezone stored in the database as timezone.name ie. America/Eastern. For the countdown the $offset is created from this value being -4 so the input to the countdown is

```
-4, 2012, 8 - 1, 28, 00, 00, 00
```

Which work for the jquery counter I am using but it doesnt work when trying to compare current date to the mysql date entry. I have tried setting the timezone before getting the mysql datetime entry and storing a value like this for eastern

```
2012-08-27 20:00:00
```

when I try to set current time and I use my America/Phoenix timezone I get a value that is at 9pm when the eastern post should expire I get

```
2012-08-28 21:00:00
```

which to me means the post would have expired an hour early. This is were I am stuck I am open to storing the data in multiple db entries on for the countdown and one for the expiration db check I just dont know what the best way to achieve what I need is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Mr. Bruce!

Comment: Are these posts made by 'users'? Do they have defined timezones saved somewhere? Do your dates in the DB all use the same timezone?(UTC?)
It might be easier to save all dates as UTC in timestamp fields in the DB, and every date coming out of it will be run through a function that displays in the users timezone, and everydate going in converts it from the users timezone to UTC.

Posting this in a comment because I wouldn't call it an 'answer' to your question necessarily as it requires possibly a lot of extra changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would convert all expiration times to UTC (or some other defined timezone - maybe that of your DB server and application server if they are the same) before entering them into the database table and then query against that table based on the the timezone of the particular user.  So for example the WHERE clause might look like

```
WHERE expiration_datetime > NOW() + INTERVAL X HOUR
```

where X is where you apply the hour difference for user's timezone.

Comment: So when you say UTC I would store the datetime after applying the timezone offset ie. midnight eastern is stored as 2012-08-27 20:00:00 is this right?

Comment: Yes.  Make any timezone adjustments you need to make to the expiration date before storing it in the database.  Again I just used UTC as an example.  You could really use any time zone you want so long as you standardize all your application logic on using that timezone for the database and making conversions from it as needed for localize time zones.

Comment: When I store the values in UTC and get the current datetime the values expire early as in my original post example if I store in values UTC how do I get the current time for different users across differnt timezones to get the correct datetime.

Comment: @WilliamBruce What you are storing in your database is the absolute time at which the item expires.  In you application logic you would need to understand what the user's current timezone is, and what the difference between this time zone and the time zone stored in the database is, in order to formulate the query on the database to select current items (i.e. your application will need to determine the value of `X` in the WHERE clause example I noted in my answer).  I am assuming you already have some logic in your application to determine the users' timezone.

Comment: I think I am missing something. So I am storing the post expiration timezone (US/Eastern) in DB field and I know the users timezone as (US/Arizona). So the interval is 3. But now plus 3 would work if I stored the value as 2012-08-27 00:00:00 but not if I apply the timezone of the post before storing to DB as 2012-08-27 20:00:00

Comment: @WilliamBruce My suggestion was to discontinue use of the DB filed related to the timezone the datetime was stored and and to simply store all expiration datetimes in a common timezone. So, to simplify the example, let's say you decide to use EST as the common datetime (rather than UTC). Let's say an items is to expire at midnight on some day.  You would store the expiration datetime as 2012-08-27 00:00:00.  If the user was on west cost the offer should expire for him at 2012-08-26 21:00:00. Continued...

Comment: The time difference is -3 hours for PST, so the where clause would look like `WHERE expiration_datetime > NOW() + INTERVAL -3 HOUR`  If the user was in Atlantic timezone (one hour ahead of EST).  The WHERE clause would look like `WHERE expiration_datetime > NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR` and so on.  If your common datetime is UTC rather than EST, you would just substract 5 from the local timezone values to where PST would be -8, Atlantic would be -4, EST would be -5, etc. The only logic you would need in the app is to know the interval from the common timezone for each user timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You got your database designed wrong if you allow posts timestamp to be not normalized. I is irrelevant what timezone user is in as long as all the timestamp are in the same timezone there's no big deal. So answer to your question is - fix your desing, keep all timestamps in the same timezone (GMT for simplicity).